# Python: function, for loop, error message

Tags: python-2.7

I am pretty new to Python and am practicing with codeacademy, am getting a strange error message with below function. I dont understand as it looks logically and syntactically correct to me, can anyone see the issue?

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        total = total + item
    return total
```

Oops, try again.

```
compute_bill(['apple'])
```

resulted in a

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Yes, `0 + 'apple'` is not a meaningful operation in Python. You can only add numbers or concatenate strings, not add strings to numbers.

Comment: are you supposed to pass `apple`'s  price ?

Comment: Hi, yes. I am supposed to pass the price

Comment: ok, so your issue is resolved. Is it ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a `string` with an `integer` . 
typeError on python Docs -[typeError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError)

call the function like below-

```
compute_bill([1]) 
compute_bill([10,20,30])
```

OR

```
apple = 10
orange = 20
compute_bill([apple,orange])
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Rilwan said in his answer yo cannot add string with an interger. Since you are working on codeacademy, i have completed similar assignment, I believe you have to get the cost of the food that you send to the function from a dictionary and then calculate the total.

```
food_cost = { "apples" : 20, "oranges" : 40}
def compute_bill(food):
     total = 0
     for item in food:
         total = total + food_cost[item]
     return total
compute_bill(['apples'])
```